# Zerotier ssh fails from one particular computer (works fine from other devices)

Tags: networking, ssh, vpn

I have a Zerotier vpn set up so that I can ssh into my office computer (Ubuntu) from my laptop (Windows), and recently helped set up the same for a friend (Ubuntu to Ubuntu). Everything seems to be identical between the two cases - we literally scrolled through our two Zerotier network manager pages side-by-side to see whether we had all settings set to the same - but my friend can't connect to their computer from home. Whenever they try

```
ssh name@10.xxx.xxx.xx
```

(I've censored the name and ip here, but obviously they're using their correct user account name and the correct ip, not a bunch of x's)

they get

```
ssh: connect to host 10.xxx.xxx.xx port 22: No route to host
```

They also added *my* home laptop to the network so that I could try connecting, and that worked fine - I was able to log in, work remotely on their desktop, and `pscp` files back and forth with no trouble, just like with my own office desktop.

So, whatever the precise cause of the error is, it seems that it cannot reside in either the target machine or the Zerotier network itself, but must be located in the source laptop.

Unfortunately, googling the error message was little help, so I turned here for help. Is there any way to resolve this? Or at least any place to begin looking?

Comment: Same problem, i can connect to port 80, 554 and other no problem just SSH.
If you TCPDUMP the network you can see the packages do arrive to the target they just froze or stop communicating. It might be an SSH setting.